# A question of J.P.May's algebraic topology.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I wonder how May constructed the last step of the proof of Proposition witch is on page 8 of  *A Concise Course in algebraic topology*? I tried to construct it as follows:Let $y_0=p(x),y_1=q(x)$ and $y_t=h(0,t)$. Define $\gamma_t(s)=a((1-s)t+s)$ is a path from $y_t$ to $y_1$. Then, we have $\gamma_0(s)=a(s),\gamma_1(s)=a(1)=c_{q(x)}$. We want to proof:$c_{p(x)}\simeq a^{-1}\cdot(q\circ f)^{-1}\cdot a\cdot (p\circ f)$. So we define a homotopy as follows:

$$\gamma_t^{-1}\cdot j^{-1}\cdot\gamma_t\cdot j=\begin{cases} j(4s,t),&0\le s\le\frac{1}{4}\\
\gamma_t(4s-1),&\frac{1}{4}\le s\le \frac{1}{2}\\
j(4s-2,1-t),&\frac{1}{2}\le s\le\frac{3}{4}\\
\gamma_t^{-1}(4s-3),&\frac{3}{4}\le s\le 1.\end{cases}$$

When $t=0$, we have $\gamma_0^{-1}\cdot j^{-1}\cdot\gamma_0\cdot j=a^{-1}\cdot(q\circ f)^{-1}\cdot a\cdot(p\circ f)$; when $t=1$, we have $\gamma_1^{-1}\cdot j^{-1}\cdot\gamma_1\cdot j=c_{p(x)}$. So $c_{p(x)}\simeq a^{-1}\cdot(q\circ f)^{-1}\cdot a\cdot(p\circ f)$.

I don't know if I'm doing this correctly?If not, can you tell me the correct way to construct it?
[image]